# How to change EditText input type from password to visible?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an EditText for inputting password and a checkbox below it to show password when it is checked. How can i implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it this code

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked) {
                        password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                    } else {
                        password.setInputType(129);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: On unchecking it, i would want it to go back to the password form. This code doesnt do that. How can that be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | Input.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: Please define `Input` in  this `Input.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
    if (!isChecked) {
                  // show password
               mEtPwd.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance())
        } else {
                 // hide password                
               mEtPwd.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        }
```